# No value accessor for form control with name

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I am using Angular Material in one of my angular2+ project. I am using `mat-list` in a with a reactive forms. I've given `formControlName` to the `mat-list`, but I am getting the following error:

> No value accessor for form control with name:

I could use `mat-selection-list` which supports `formControlName`, but it enables multiple selection and shows a `checkbox`. I do now want to show the checkbox and only want to select one item at a time.

could some one please help me with how to use `formControlName` with `mat-list`.

thanks

HTML code:

```
<div [formGroup]="activityForm">
 <mat-list formControlName="activityId">
  <mat-list-item *ngFor="let act of activities">
   {{act.name}}      
  </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

Comment: Post your HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current state (v5.2.4), the `mat-list` does not implement the necessary changes in order to support a Custom `ControlValueAccessor`. You will have to write your own for this component if it is what you need to do: [Angular docs for ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor).